# Regular expression in java data extract

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract data from a string. For this i use pattern compile and match class.
But i am having difficulty in developing regular expression for following string.

```
"<WebApicall id="4" time="2013-10-05; 22:44:18" timeStamp="|18|44|22|5|9|113|6|277|0|" tick="11589293" file="self" bdlLine="61" type="url" url="http://www.google.com/"> WebUrl </WebApicall>"
```

now from above link i want data 4, 2013-10-05; 22:44:18, etc.
So how can i build regular expression.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What did you try? Seems pretty straight-forward, if you even *need* a reg ex.

Comment: Why not use an XML parser for this?

Comment: ok. bt i dont know xml parser. Can you tell me what it is and any best link to learn?

Comment: Use [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) for this task.

Comment: ok Rohit. Will try and will get back if i have any doubt. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://regexr.com?36n7q) is the regular expression:

```
^<WebApicall\s+id=\"(\d+)\"\s+time=\"(.*)\"\s+timeStamp=\"(\|?\d+\|)+\"\s+tick=\"(\d+)\".*url=\"(.*)\">
```

And here a java snippet that shows how it can be used:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

 ...

String id;
String time;
String timeStamp;
String tick;
String url;

 ...

String textual = "<WebApicall id="4" time="2013-10-05; 22:44:18" timeStamp="|18|44|22|5|9|113|6|277|0|" tick="11589293" file="self" bdlLine="61" type="url" url="http://www.google.com/"> WebUrl </WebApicall>";
String regex = "^<WebApicall\\s+id=\\\"(\\d+)\\\"\\s+time=\\\"(.*)\\\"\\s+timeStamp=\\\"(\\|?\\d+\\|)+\\\"\\s+tick=\\\"(\\d+)\\\".*url=\\\"(.*)\\\">";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(textual);
if (m.matches()) {
  id = m.group(1);
  time = m.group(2);
  timeStamp = m.group(3);
  tick = m.group(4);
  url = m.group(5);
   ...
}
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to grab everything within quotes, you could use something like this: `"([^"]+)"`

This regex has its pitfalls though, but unless you specify your needs more clearly, this will have to do.

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/qJ6jY8

Comment: This is not giving me my expected result. Previously i had tried (.*?) , but this too didn't worked. Any other regex, which could help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should use jsoup for parsing html/xml. It allows you to use selectors so you can grab exactly  what you need.  If you must use regex then use 
`Matcher`.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("id=\"(.*)\" time=\"(.*) \"tick" ).matcher(myXmlString);

List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
while (m.find()) {
    matches.add(m.group(1));
    matches.add(m.group(2));
}
```